# Keep getting an error when running the LDA function in R, I am using the MASS library for the LDA

Tags: r, lda

I having trouble with the LDA function in R. Any help would be great!.

```
 > bond <- read.csv("BondRating.csv")
 > head(bond)

RATING OBS CODERTG LOPMAR LFIXCHAR LGEARRAT LTDCAP LLEVER LCASHLTD LACIDRAT LCURRAT LRECTURN LASSLTD

1    AAA ,  8,       1, -1.323,    0.998,   -0.936,  0.281,-0.042,   -0.187  0.001,   0.863,    1.349,   1.704,

2    AAA,   9,       1, -2.100,    1.516,   -1.654,  0.159, 0.251,    0.342,   -0.077,   0.347,    1.762,   2.515,

> lda(RATING~.,data = bond)

Error in lda.default(x, grouping, ...) :
```

variable 2 appears to be constant within groups

```
 'data.frame':  14 obs. of  13 variables:
$ RATING  : Factor w/ 7 levels "A","AA","AAA",..: 3 3 2 2 1 1 6 6 5 5 ...
$ OBS     : int  8 9 23 24 37 38 52 53 67 68 ...
$ CODERTG : int  1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 ...
$ LOPMAR  : num  -1.32 -2.1 -1.74 -1.78 -1.7 ...
$ LFIXCHAR: num  0.998 1.516 1.626 1.153 3.691 ...
$ LGEARRAT: num  -0.936 -1.654 -1.207 -0.45 -3.155 ...
$ LTDCAP  : num  0.281 0.159 0.23 0.389 0.04 0.369 0.249 0.257 0.233 0.288 ...
$ LLEVER  : num  -0.042 0.251 -0.066 0.171 -0.936 0.013 -0.101 -0.049 -0.244 -0.024 ...
$ LCASHLTD: num  -0.187 0.342 -0.266 -0.898 1.573 ...
$ LACIDRAT: num  0.001 -0.077 -0.229 -0.073 0.122 0.07 -0.709 -0.225 0.022 -0.006 ...
$ LCURRAT : num  0.863 0.347 0.543 0.44 0.998 0.781 0.787 0.476 0.726 0.569 ...
$ LRECTURN: num  1.35 1.76 1.72 2.23 2.03 ...
$ LASSLTD : num  1.7 2.52 1.92 1.25 3.49 ...
```

Comment: It doesn't seem right if your data has comma there. I believe they should be numeric or categorical type, shouldn't they?

Comment: `str(bond)`, please ... ?

Comment: I actually figured it out. The str(bond) actually helped me see what was wrong.   having both RATING and CODERTG was messing up the LDA. They have the same information just written differently

Answer (score 2):

Remove CODERTG, redundant information since its is the same as  RATING

```
 lda(RATING~OBS+CODERTG+LOPMAR+LFIXCHAR+LGEARRAT+LTDCAP+LLEVER+LCASHLTD+LACIDRAT+LCURRAT+LRECTURN+LASSLTD, data=bond)

Call:
lda(RATING ~ OBS + LOPMAR + LFIXCHAR + LGEARRAT + LTDCAP + LLEVER + 
LCASHLTD + LACIDRAT + LCURRAT + LRECTURN + LASSLTD, data = bond)

Prior probabilities of groups:
    A        AA       AAA         B        BA       BAA         C 
 0.1428571 0.1428571 0.1428571 0.1428571 0.1428571 0.1428571 0.1428571
```